# Where to find dimensions for DJI Phantom 3 gimbal?

Tags: dji, drone-frame, gimbal

Basically I am trying to make my own drone with carbon fiber rods and 3d printed connectors. I have selected a battery, motors, propellers, etc. I also have a DJI phantom 3 drone which I would like to use the gimbal and camera from. The flight controller I plan to use is the DJI NAZA M lite.

There are two things I need to know that I cannot find. One is if I can take the gimbal and camera off from the DJI phantom 3 and connect it to the NAZA M lite flight controller. The second is the dimensions and spacing of the screws that hold the bottom of the gimbal to the drone. I have read a lot of documentation but cannot seem to find this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I FOUND A 3D MODEL ON THINGIVERSE
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1645181